# Extracting information based on a pattern with comma delimited text

Tags: r

I am working with a large data set and need to clean the data. In the following example, I want to know which rows of a column display NIH and NIA that are not preceded by any additional information. More precisely, NIH or NIA alone at the beginning of a row; or NIH or NIA alone between two semi-colons. In my example, an additional column containing logical results (TRUE or FALSE) would be sufficient.

NHI; National Institutes of Health, NIH; National Institute on Aging, NIA; Fogarty International Center, FIC; Institute for Translational Neuroscience, ITN; International Brain Research Organization, IBRO; Sveriges Tandläkarförbund, SDA; NIA; National Institute of Neurological Disorders and Stroke

As requested by @I_O:

```
df <- data.frame(Funding = c("NHI; National Institutes of Health, NIH; National Institute on Aging, NIA; Fogarty International Center, FIC; Institute for Translational Neuroscience, ITN; International Brain Research Organization, IBRO; Sveriges Tandläkarförbund, SDA; NIA; National Institute of Neurological Disorders and Stroke", "Canadian Partnership for Stroke Recovery; EuroImmun; National Institutes of Health, NIH; U.S. Department of Defense, DOD; National Institute on Aging, NIA; National Institute of Biomedical Imaging and Bioengineering, NIBIB; Michael J. Fox Foundation for Parkinson's Research, MJFF; Alzheimer's Association, AA; Alzheimer's Disease Neuroimaging Initiative, ADNI; Fondation Brain Canada; Northern California Institute for Research and Education, NCIRE; Sunnybrook Research Institute, SRI; Weston Brain Institute, WBI; Canadian Institutes of Health Research, IRSC; Alzheimer’s Research UK, ARUK", "National Institutes of Health, NIH; National Institute on Aging, NIA; National Institute of Diabetes and Digestive and Kidney Diseases, NIDDK; National Institute of Child Health and Human Development, NICHD; National Institute of Child Health and Human Development", "Institute for Neurological Research; Research and Development Grants for Dementia; NIA; Alzheimer's Association, AA; Japan Agency for Medical Research and Development, AMED; Consejo Nacional de Investigaciones Científicas y Técnicas, CONICET; Korea Health Industry Development Institute, KHIDI; Deutsches Zentrum für Neurodegenerative Erkrankungen, DZNE", "National Institutes of Health, NIH; National Institute on Aging, NIA; Alzheimer's Association, AA; Global Brain Health Institute; Rainwater Charitable Foundation, RCF"))
```

Comment: Please supply some sample data and structure by pasting the output of `dput(head(your_data))`.

Comment: Hi @I_O, I have included a data frame as an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using {dplyr} and {tidyr} for convenience:

1. to have one row per project and sponsor:

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    
    df |>
    mutate(project_no = row_number(), .before = 1) |>
    separate_rows(Funding, sep = '\\s*;\\s*') |>
    mutate(NIH_or_NIA = grepl('NIA|NIH', Funding))
```

output:

```
    # A tibble: 42 x 3
       project_no Funding                                                 NIH_or_NIA
            <int> <chr>                                                   <lgl>     
     1          1 NHI                                                     FALSE     
     2          1 National Institutes of Health, NIH                      TRUE      
     3          1 National Institute on Aging, NIA                        TRUE      
     4          1 Fogarty International Center, FIC                       FALSE 
## ...
```

2. to only check whether any of the sponsors is funding a project:

```
df |>
mutate(project_no = row_number(), .before = 1) |>
separate_rows(Funding, sep = '\\s*;\\s*') |>
summarise(NIH_or_NIA = any(grepl('NIA|NIH', Funding)),
          .by = project_no
          )
```

output:

```
    # A tibble: 5 x 2
      project_no NIH_or_NIA
           <int> <lgl>     
    1          1 TRUE      
    2          2 TRUE      
    3          3 TRUE      
    4          4 TRUE      
    5          5 TRUE
```